# Icon Position changes while using icons from native base in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am adding images here of the button I am getting the problem.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHBXa.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hazGW.png)

The one having an arrow in the center is when I launch only that particular screen.
The other image where the arrow seems to be distorted from the center is when this screen comes in my complete app flow.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { Title, Label, Button, Icon, Row } from 'native-base';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class abc extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground 
                    <Row style={StylesNew.Containor}>
                        <Button icon block style={StylesNew.nextButton}
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('xyz')}>
                            <Icon name='arrow-right' type='FontAwesome5' style={StylesNew.Icon} />
                        </Button>
                    </Row>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    };
}
export default withNavigation(abc);
```

Styling code is as below

```
 Containor: {
       justifyContent: 'flex-end',
       margin: WIDTH / 9,
       flex: 1,
       alignSelf: 'flex-end'
   },
 nextButton: {
       width: HEIGHT / 12,
       height: HEIGHT / 12,
       borderRadius: HEIGHT / 24,
       backgroundColor: pinkcolor,
       alignSelf: 'flex-end',
   },
 Icon: {
       color: blackcolor,
       alignSelf: 'center',
       fontSize: WIDTH / 15
   },
```

**Expected behaviour**
Icon position should remain the same.

**Actual behaviour**
Icon position changes when the screen appears on the complete app flow.

Comment: The issue was with react-native-vector-icon type. By changing the type of the icons to ionicon it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

change your nextbutton

```
nextButton: {
           width: HEIGHT / 12,
           height: HEIGHT / 12,
           borderRadius: HEIGHT / 24,
           backgroundColor: pinkcolor,
           alignSelf: 'center',
           alignItem:'center'
       },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this didn't work for me. Here the problem is with icon inside the button and the changes you mentioned are applied to the entire button. So these seem to be in no relation with the icon position.

Comment: try to add  **alignSelf: 'center',** in icon style.and add **justifyContent:'center'** in nextbutton style.if its work